# JQuery Hover Function Timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, settimeout

I've seen other similar questions to this on SO but the answers weren't quite what I'm looking for. My problem with the code below is about the variable **hide**.

In it's current form **hide** won't be visible to the first hover function, but I don't want to declare it at a higher scope because it has no use there. Plus declaring it at a higher scope would require making a different variable for every li.

What's the solution for keeping this variable containing a timeout between these two functions?

```
$('li').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(hide);
    $('.menu', this).show();
}, function() {
    var menu = $('.menu', this);
    var hide = setTimeout(function() {
        menu.hide();
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the value with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$('li').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('hide'));
    $('.menu', this).show();
}, function() {
    var menu = $('.menu', this);
    $(this).data('hide', setTimeout(function() {
        menu.hide();
    }, 500));
});
```